# How to show $\langle a, b \; | \; aba = bab \rangle \cong \langle x,y \; | \; x^3=y^2 \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do these two presentations present the same group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101720/why-do-these-two-presentations-present-the-same-group)

I wanted to work my way through the lecture notes of a lecture called "Reflection Groups" and already have problems solving one of the first (probably very simple) exercises given.

> Show: $\langle a, b \; | \; aba = bab \rangle \cong \langle x,y \; | \; x^3=y^2 \rangle$.

I already solved a few other, similar exercises, however I just have no idea how to do this one, and before I continue my reading, I wanted to find an answer for that exercise. Wikipedia told me that the latter presentation was a group presentation of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, but that does not really help me.

I hope that somebody can help me out and thank you very much in advance for an answer.

Comment: Are these notes online? If so could you post the link? I would be interested in taking a look

Comment: @Edison: The notes are online, but in German. (http://www.math.ethz.ch/~suter/refl.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $x\mapsto ab$, $y\mapsto aba$

Comment: How does one come up with such a map?

Comment: Noting that $(aba)(bab)=(ab)(ab)(ab)$.

Comment: @Huy: What Alex says. Experience with reflection groups also helps :-)